# Brightness flickering on Lenovo Yoga 720 | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: display

I have a Lenovo Yoga 720 and am running Ubuntu 18.04. The screen changes brightness automatically every 5-10 sec. This does not happen with Ubuntu 17 or Windows 10 (dual boot). Please assist.

```
description: Convertible
product: 81C3 (LENOVO_MT_81C3_BU_idea_FM_YOGA 720-13IKB)
vendor: LENOVO
version: Lenovo YOGA 720-13IKB
serial: MP1CHKDC
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 smp vsyscall32
```

Answer (score 18):

This may be caused by the adaptive brightness setting. I had the same issue. It's way too aggressive for my preferences.

Go to Settings > Power then turn automatic brightness off

Comment: Wow, what a poorly executed feature. I thought this was a graphics driver bug, changed my drivers, switched to wayland then believed it must have been a hardware failure. Thanks for the tip, this saved me hours more debugging and perhaps buying a new computer!

Comment: I spent one hour debugging kernel options for i915 (yoga 910) only to find this is the issue, because I didn't imagine they would implement an auto brightness that changes all the time in such a distracting manner. People generally don't expect your brightness to keep changing randomly dozens of times a minute (really) with constant ambient light.

Comment: This solved the same problem on a Lenovo Yoga 730-15IKB

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me bonkers on my Yoga.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 from 16.04 on my XMG C404 laptop.
Changing the Refresh Rate of my screen helped yesterday, today I'm back to flickering, although less often/disturbing than before. Any news what could be the cause?

Settings > Displays > Refresh Rate
I reduced it from initially 60Hz to 59.96Hz. And then also tried increasing to 120Hz.